# PHPMailer / Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer

olá, boa tarde a todos.
estou com uma duvida em relação ao projeto que me foi dado.
tenho que criar um cliente de email dentro da plataforma em codeigniter que está sendo desenvolvida, já pesquisei e vi como faço para enviar emails via ssl, mas oque me falta saber é
como faço a listagem dos emails da caixa de entrada do usuario? isso seria capaz? 
existe alguma API que eu possa consumir para fazer essa listagem??

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).